# How do I assign an event handler to an event in C++/CLI?

Tags: c#, .net, events, c++-cli, event-handling

How do I add "events" to an "event"/delegate?  What is the syntax?
Is it the same in C++/CLI and in C#?

Comment: Should be "How do I (register) **assign an event handler** to an event"? Add an event handler using UI and check the resulting code.

Comment: In c++ you can use the _hookevent and UNHookEvent or else use the implement the observer pattern

Comment: @Jaroslav i want to add an event to an already existing event.  not to create a new one.

Comment: Adding **events** means *creating* new events. Adding **event handlers** means *subscribing* to events so when an event is fired, your assigned handler methods get executed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), you do it with the `+=` operator:

```
someObj.SomeEvent += new EventHandler(Blah_SomeEvent);
```

...

```
private void Blah_SomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

#### More-than-a-year-later-edit

*It has been a long time since I posted this answer and someone noticed me that maybe it was wrong. I really don't know why the OP marked my answer as the right one (maybe OP was looking for this rather than [c++-cli](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli) syntax? Who knows now)*.

*Anyway, in [c++-cli](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli) it would be:*

```
someObj->SomeEvent+= gcnew EventHandler(this, &Blah_SomeEvent);
```

Comment: Oh, I find the answers to simple questions are just an important. Helps when the next user searches for the same thing :)

Comment: Right, we avoid redundancy. But you forgot that most RTFM users won't search before asking haha ;)

Comment: This is not a correct answer if we look at the question title (C++/CLI is not C#).

Comment: @dacap Maybe you should downvote the question. If I'm wrong that OP looked for C# syntax, it should be that the question was incorrectly asked. Who knows why OP checked my answer as the correct one. Anyway, it seems that the OP found it useful.

Answer (score 17):

1: If underlyng delgate of the event is a custom one you define yourself that is a class memeber (example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/58cwt3zh.aspx)):

```
delegate void Del(int, float);
ref class EventReceiver {
public:
    void Handler(int i , float f) {  }
};
myEventSource->MyEvent += gcnew Del(myEventReceiver, &EventReceiver::Handler);
```

2: If the underlying delegate is a global handler and has the standard signature for .NET events (object + event args) (from DPD answer):

```
delegate void MyOwnEventHandler(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e) { }  
myEventSource->MyEvent += gcnew EventHandler(MyOwnEventHandler);
```

3: If the underlying delegate has the standard signature for .NET events and the event handler is a class method:

```
ref class EventReceiver {
public:
   void Handler(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e) {  }
};
myEventSource->MyEvent += gcnew EventHandler(myEventReceiver, &EventReceiver::Handler);
```

4: Using System::EventHandler generic (that takes a MyEventArgs args parameter) as the underlying delegate:

```
ref class EventReceiver {
public:
   void Handler(Object^ sender, MyEventArgs^ e) {  }
};
myEventSource->MyEvent += gcnew EventHandler<MyEventArgs^>(this, &EventReceiver::DataReceived);
```

Answer (score 7):

The syntax for C++/CLI is :

```
delegate void MyOwnEventHandler(Object^ sender, Eventargs^ e)
{

}
```

to register this for an event:

```
objectPtr->MyEvent += gcnew EventHandler(MyOwnEventHandler);
```