# How are WinRT / .net exceptions raised from C++/WinRT?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I've been trying to wrap regular C++ exceptions in .NET-style exceptions that can be caught from the C# code using a C++/WinRT library, to allow it to receive errors from the wrapped C++ library.

[This guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/error-handling) seems to suggest using Win32-esque HRESULTs, but returning HRESULTs would prevent us from raising errors from methods that also need to return an actual value.

Is there any way to just throw an exception from C++/WinRT (presumably not using C++'s `throw` mechanism) that can be caught from the C# layer? Regular C++ exceptions simply cause a crash without useful information.

Comment: You need to register a c++ event in c#.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942311/how-do-i-assign-an-event-handler-to-an-event-in-c-cli/16020583?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng that seems to be on the topic of Events / Delegates rather than exceptions?

Comment: An exception is an event!!!

Comment: No, it isn't. The fact that you can register a delegate for the unhandled exception event doesn't make any exception an event source. At the ABI you'd want to use [RoOriginateLanguageException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/roerrorapi/nf-roerrorapi-rooriginatelanguageexception) to wrap arbitrary exception information inside a COM object. [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55850558/1889329) has more information on the topic.

Comment: The simple solution is to just [throw_hresult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/error-handling/throw-hresult) from C++/WinRT code and have the language projection deal with the rest. That certainly leads to somewhat dissatisfying error granularity. With JavaScript still a supported WinRT language there's not much to expect in regards to better exception propagation. Unfortunately.